# reduceByKey using Scala object as key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

I'm using spark with scala and I've a RDD full of tuple2 containing a complex object as key and a double. The aim is to add the double (the frequency) if the object are identical.

for that I've defined my object as follow :

```
    case class SimpleCoocurrence(word:String, word_pos:String, cooc:String, cooc_pos:String, distance:Double) extends Ordered[SimpleCoocurrence]{
      def compare(that: SimpleCoocurrence) = {
        if(this.word.equals(that.word)&&this.word_pos.equals(that.word_pos)
           &&this.cooc.equals(that.cooc)&&this.cooc_pos.equals(that.cooc_pos))
          0
        else
          this.toString.compareTo(that.toString)
      }
    }
```

now I'm trying to use reduceBykey like that :

```
val coocRDD = sc.parallelize(coocList)
println(coocRDD.count)
coocRDD.map(tup=>tup).reduceByKey(_+_)
println(coocRDD.count)
```

But, the result shows that the RDD before and after processing a reducebykey contains exactly the same number of elements.

How can I perform a reduceByKey using tuple2[SimpleCoocurrence,Double] ?
Is implementing Ordered trait the good way to tell Spark how to compare my objects ?
Should I use only tuple2[String,Double] ?

thx,

Answer (score 6):

`reduceByKey` does not use Ordering but `hashCode` and `equals` to determine what keys are the same. In particular, the `hashPartitioner` will group keys by hash, sothat keys with the same hashCode fall on the same partition sothat further reduction can happen on a per-partition.

case classes have a default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`. Probably the test data used has different values of the field `distance:Double` making each instance an unique object. Using it as key will result in only identical objects being reduced as one.

One way to address this would be to define a key for your `case class` and an addition method for the object, something like this:

```
case class SimpleCoocurrence(word:String, word_pos:String, cooc:String, cooc_pos:String, distance:Double) extends Serializable {
   val key = word + word_pos + cooc + cooc_pos
}
object SimpleCoocurrence {
   val add: (SimpleCoocurrence, SimpleCoocurrence) => SimpleCoocurrence = ???
}

val coocList:List[SimpleCoocurrence] = ???
val coocRDD = sc.parallelize(coocList)
val coocByKey = coocRDD.keyBy(_.key)
val addedCooc = coocByKey.reduceByKey(SimpleCoocurrence.add)
```

(*) code provided as guiding example - not compiled or tested.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm dumb...

Next, in case anyone have the same problem and want to use complex scala objects as Key for a reduceByKey on Spark:

Spark knows how to compare two object even if they do not implement Ordered. So the code above is actualy fonctionnal.

The only problem was... that I was printing the same RDD before and after. When I write this, it actualy works well.

```
val coocRDD = sc.parallelize(coocList)
println(coocRDD.count)
val newRDD = coocRDD.map(tup=>tup).reduceByKey(_+_)
println(newRDD.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the results of reduceByKey. Try this instead:

```
val coocRDD = sc.parallelize(coocList)
println(coocRDD.count)
val result = coocRDD.map(tup=>tup).reduceByKey(_+_)
println(result.count)
```